# correct preposition for rate

Tags: prepositions

Which preposition is correct to be used in the following sentence?

> Sea levels are estimated to be rising **with / at** a rate of 1.8mm
> per year.

Why is the other one wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"**At** a rate of" is more idiomatic.

Comment: Thanks. "with" is wrong?

Comment: @a.toraby It's unnatural